# Keep laptop sound device from shutting down after some time of standby

Tags: windows-10, laptop, audio, drivers, dell-latitude

I have 2 problems with my laptop:

- (a) When playing, starting a video or audio file or a stream (youtube for example) the audio starts 4 seconds late (no sync issues, just no sound for the first few seconds)
- (b) When switching video or audio source fast, volume goes up to 100% (when audio source starts for 2-3 seconds and then starts from other source, youtube playlist next video, while playing video in vlc, opening another file from folder, video stops for some time, next one plays)

My trial & error & some you should knows and let's divide the problems to a & b.

- I can be somewhat considered as a poweruser (talk tech, no need to translate to "normal" language)
- I have not been able to solve it in any way. I think it is because the audio board or something there is shutting down to save power. I am looking for an option for keeping it on always or some somewhat easy to reach switch (software) to manually make it always on mode. (this is the solve from a)
- I was able to download and install a generic driver directly from Realtek's website and install it. But there occurred serval problems: The headphones or external speakers didn't work. In Realtek's software what came with the driver it detected it, but in windows playback devices it showed it was playing sound, but nothing came out. If in Realtek software I selected to separate the sound outputs then the sound came out of laptop's speakers and windows playback devices showed headphones were unplugged.

Notes:

1. in Realtek's software it thought, that headphones were plugged in as in the front plug and back was unplugged.
2. When from windows search and taskbar and task manager startup & proceses there was 1 Realtek software, but from control panel Hardware & Sound there was 2. 1 was the "normal", looked something like this:
   [image]
   but at the right there was only analog with back & front, (I say greyed out means plugged out and normal plugged in) and the 2nd one looked like the right bar only.
3. After opening the 2nd from control panel, every time instead of one wich device did you plug in with options of external audio & headphones I got 1 from both of them (tried both, no sound from headphones)
4. Dell doesn't work well with drivers. I had an issue with the touchpad since Windows 10 messed everything up. The middle click didn't work, resulted getting some really old Synaptics driver to make it work. Because the ones Dell provides do not work and Dell has some sort of rollback "feature" (even turning it off doesn't work) what ruined everything on that and after 1 restart also rolls the Realtek nonheadphoneworking driver(& software) back to Dell's maxaudio or some sort. That has the I like to put your volume to 100% problem.
5. Problem b doesn't occur with playing music from groove nor steam music player.
6. Problem b isn't windows, because the 100% can be brought down by readjusting sound level, when sound board is 100%, windows hiddenly thinks let's say 26% and then I press a volume + button it goes to 28% then it says to soundboard to 28% now and then it goes. It is the sound board freaking out
7. I may refer the audio thingy as a card, by that I meant laptop's internal built into motherboard audio.

Problem Solves Ranked:

1. Some Driver fix, what works great, like a normal driver should and a way that it isn't rolled back by Dell (Note: Some forums say if you install the new driver multiple times it will sometimes stay)
2. Program what plays passive noise, what is not audible (thinking of lowest or highest hertz) or if needed as little as possible audible. (googled around, didn't find one and as of right now I am unable to program one (really not in to complicated code, can edit it, but can't create) so it would be really nice, if someone good would program one.) (possibly can be closed by running it by argument /q or somehow other) (auto startup can be managed by start up folder.)

It's a Dell Latitude E7440, if you need some more info, feel free to comment.

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  Please edit your question, and clarify your question, do not clarify your question with a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got foobar2000 as a lightweight program, and made 24h silence with audacity. Then I placed the 24h in the startup folder and made an ahk script, what hides it on startup. The audio file was .aiff format, so foobar2000 wouldn't play mp3 by default and only .aiff files. Unfortionetly it captures my media keys, so the playback of it would stop. If you want to say it that if media keys pressed, then do nothing, but it has a weird problem, that when you make it global, then it hijacks the key, making my normal media player useless at reciving it. Then I decided to let it be and every time I press `e` it would play again (`e` is the most common character) but then I realized, that I couldn't type `e` anymore. Since it blocks all keys you map it to, i decided to map play to `fn` + `f3` what is `scroll lock`. So if i realise it is happening again, I could press it manually, but I wrote a simple ahk script, what does it for me every 10 seconds.  Theses days AHK does it all. Also the sound to 100% problem still is there.